# PDO/SQL returning 0, in Navicat working

Tags: php, sql, pdo, navicat

I am trying to Select data from my db using PDO. However whenever I run the query PDO "rowCount()" returns 0 affected rows. When I run the same query in Navicat, I get the appropriate rows returned.

My Code:

```
$select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT columnName FROM tblName WHERE columName2 = :val1 AND `value` = :val2");

          $select->execute(
                    array(
                        ":val1" => "data1",
                        ":val2" => "data2"
                        )
                    );
```

I configured PDO to throw errors and my code runs in a try/catch block. The try part is executed till the end, no exceptions thrown.

What I want to achieve: Get appropriate rows and insert into new table.

Any ideas on where my problem could be?

EDIT:

```
try {
            $dbh->beginTransaction();//drop/create table
            if($dbh->exec("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblName") === false)
            {
                $dbh->rollback();
                exit($dbh->errInfo());
            }
            if($dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE tblName (id bigint);") === false)
            {
                $dbh->rollback();
                exit($dbh->errInfo());
            }
            $dbh->commit();//save table
            $dbh->beginTransaction();//insert transaction
            $put = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tblName (id) VALUES (:id)");
            $bind = array(
                ":id" => null
                );
            $a = "string";
        //  $b = "[lang_es]string[/lang_es][lang_en]string[/lang_en]";


            $select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT columnName FROM tblName WHERE columnName = :val1 ");
            // AND `value` = :val2");
            $select->bindValue(":val1", $a);
        //  $select->bindValue(":val2", $b);
            $select->execute();

            print_r($select);
            while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                $bind[":id"] = $row["columName"];
                $put->execute($bind);//inserts row
                $put->closeCursor();//optional
            }
            $dbh->commit();//save changes to db

        var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());
        }
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($select->fetchAll());` show?

Comment: @Lucas array (size=0) empty

Comment: you also haven't specified the database, maybe do you need to begin a transaction, or maybe you aren't connected, or maybe the query has an error, try `var_dump($dbh->errorInfo());` to shed light on it.

Comment: @Lucas 
gives me: array (size=3)
  0 => string '00000' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null
my code runs within a transaction, connection works (I am creating a table first to put the result of the select query, table is created)

Comment: @Lucas could it be something to do with the escaping of "value"? or my data2 containing "[]/".
I mean it would not make much sense because in Navicat the query is working fine...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but with a prepared statement, it is not necessary to sanitize the data. Without proper information I can only really throw out guesses, there are too many different database quirks or possible code alterations that could have been made to just give an answer I'm afraid.

Comment: @Lucas I meant because "value" is a fixed keyword that happens to be the columnname. What information would you need? I know that the connection is working, alterations in the DB are made by a different line of code `($dbh->exec("CREATE TABLE tblname (columname values);)`

Comment: If you can make it work in one medium there should be no reason it won't work in another, like I said there are many quirks.

Comment: @Lucas thats exactly my problem... what could be one of the more likely ones?

Comment: Check connection to database, check query, check errors. Again without knowing more information it could be something as simple as the php user not having permission to access the table, maybe another query was aborting the transaction, maybe your php values are different from the navicat values... you really need to provide the details otherwise it could be anything.

Comment: @Lucas which details exactly do you need?

Comment: What database is this and have you tried running your exact query that worked in navicat? if you are running through a series of steps it would help to show the steps, for example you mentioned that you are creating a table, do you do this every time? if so perhaps you are getting a 'table already exists' error, or maybe you don't have permission to create the table, so the query returns no results... again I am just guessing- it really is down to you to provide the details.

Comment: @Lucas there seems to be a problem with `AND /`value/` = :val2` When i take this part out of the query i get results returned, however still there is nothing inserted into the db insert using: `while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {$bind[":id"] = $row["columnName"]; $put->execute($bind);//inserts row
$put->closeCursor();//optional
}  $put = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tblName (id) VALUES (:id)");`

Comment: check your php error log

Comment: @Lucas I know for a fact that the script works, I am using it somewhere else with no problems. I only changed the query this time and it stopped working... dumping the erros reveals no errors. However when i delete The AND value part i get a result, the insert however still wont work

Comment: If you aren't getting a database error then you probably missed something in the php, I'm not sure what else to say, there is clearly a lot of other code you are using besides that one part and changing something there may have caused an error, sometimes these things can be frustrating but it's worth it when you find it.

Comment: @Lucas My code see edit. I commented the "value" part out and now I get a result and the insert works but not with the value part included nothing works.

Comment: If that is the exact php as is written, then `CREATE TABLE tblName (id bigint);` is creating a table with only the column "id" so looking for column "columName", or "value" will not find anything because they don't exist. Also I believe "errInfo" is a misspelling of errorInfo, plus it returns an array so you will only recieve an error if you do not use print_r or var_dump to display them.

Comment: The table and columnNames match and exist, should have made it more clear in my edit, sorry! But the script runs through and is not exited, so there cant be anything wrong there

Comment: as it read this is what you are telling the php to do: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tblName` drops table (if exists) `CREATE TABLE tblName (id bigint);` creates table with 1 column "id" `$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO tblName (id) VALUES (:id)");` prepares to insert into newly created table `SELECT columnName FROM tblName WHERE columnName = :val1` selects columns from the newly created table tblName. You are selecting from and inserting into an empty table.

Comment: @Lucas i am selecting from a different table, i need specific info of that table into the new table for an update script. should have been more clear about that in my update

Answer (score 0):

Because execute take just list of arguments to placeholders.

```
$select = $dbh->prepare("SELECT columnName FROM tblName WHERE columName2 = ? AND `value` = ?");

$select->execute(
    array(
        'data1', 
        'data2',
    )
);
```

Comment: Does not work... As soon as `value` is included the query does not work. Do you have any ideas about that? If I just run the part before the "AND" everything works fine...